# Wild bootstrap v Pairs and model-based bootstrap

Tags: regression, bootstrap, heteroscedasticity

When calculating the standard errors of coefficient from OLS/Huber/LTS/LMS regression models on a data set showing some levels of heteroskedasticity, Paired and model-based bootstrap give roughly similar values. However, wild bootstrap gives much smaller estimates for the standard error. Is there an explanation for this? I know wild bootstrap should take into account heteroskedasticity (unlike the other two), but I don't see how this leads to lower s.e. estimates. Or is it the case that the estimates should be similar, and I may have made a mistake with the R code?